# How to fix "Some cookies are misusing the recommended “SameSite“ attribute" warning react django axios

Tags: reactjs, django, axios, jwt

I have this `axios` function that i use to login a user (dajngo backend) then retrieving the `JWT`token as a cookie.

```
const loginRequest = (values) => {
    axios
      .post(
        "/api/login",
        {
          email: values.email,
          password: values.password,
        },{
          withCredentials: true,
          
        }
      )
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

Here is the `django view`

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def LoginView(request):
    email = request.data['email']
    password = request.data['password']

    user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()

    if user is None:
        raise AuthenticationFailed('User not found!')

    if not user.check_password(password):
        raise AuthenticationFailed('Incorrect password!')

    payload = {
            'id': user.id,
            'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60),
            'iat': datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        }
    
    token = jwt.encode(payload, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
       
    
    response = Response()

    response.set_cookie(key='jwt', value=token, httponly=True)
    response.data = {
            'jwt': token
        }
    return response
```

The cookie output (Firefox)

[image]

Then i get this warning

[image]

I tried adding `SameSite: 'None'` or `SameSite: 'Lax'` to the function

```
{
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          SameSite: 'None',
        }
```

But i get this error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add the samesite to the axios.post method, instead try to add it to this method where you set your cookie:

```
response.set_cookie(key='jwt', value=token, httponly=True)
```

Setting a cookie as part of axios.post, is now how cookies work.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)